# Show a loading animation when click submit gravity form

Tags: php, jquery, forms, wordpress, loading-animation

I am using gravity form to submit my lead to a third party the problem is when I click on submit it takes 5 seconds to get a reply and post the lead, while that is happening I want to show a loading or searching animation to the user.

I am using gravity form and I have no Idea where and how to add this function.

Can somebody please help me to get this resolved, I am not using ajax.

Comment: Sure thing. But first, [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: Are you doing it via the gform_post_submission hook?

Comment: The problem is I have no idea where to even start I am just kind of lost and some of my campaigns are live and hence don't or cant take a risk until i know where to make the changes.... any direction will be very helpful

Comment: You just need to make ajax submission true for your form. `[gravityform id="1" title="false" description="false" ajax="true"]`. In case you want to replace the default ajax spinner image, you can [check this solution](https://codexin.com/how-to-change-gravity-forms-ajax-spinner/).

Answer (score 3):

The most recent update should have a default loading image, when you have AJAX as true in the PHP shortcode.

**When AJAX attribute is true like here**

```
<?php 
    echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id="1" title="false" description="false" ajax="true"]');
?>
```

**Do this...**

To keep from getting duplicate lead submission when the submit button is clicked. Keep in mind that the Gravity Form will handle the validation. This will style the button, change the text inside of it and disable the buttons click. The loading image will show by default via Gravity Forms.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){


    $('#gform_1 input.gform_button').live('click', function(){

        submitContactForm( $(this) );

    });

});

    function submitContactForm( _this ){

        _this.die('click');
        _this.css('opacity', '0.5');
        _this.val('Sending...');

        _this.attr('disabled', 'disabled');// using this will stop the form from submitting
        $('#gform_1').submit();// this will make sure that it submits

        //console.log('calibrating...');        
    }

</script>
```

In jquery try this to override the image src when it's visible, inside of the "submitContactForm" function.

```
if ( _this.closest('.gform_footer').find('img.gform_ajax_spinner').is(':visible') ){
    _this.closest('.gform_footer').find('img.gform_ajax_spinner').attr('src','DIRECTORY OF YOUR CUSTOM SPINNER IMAGE');
}
```

So that you won't have to remember to override that image anytime that you update the Gravity Form plugin.

Comment: This code appeared to work for me, but then I ran into an issue with Firefox and the Stripe Add-on for Gravity Forms. It seems that this code interferes with Stripe.js being properly recognized in Firefox (tested version 36 and 48 on Mac and PC). Other browsers do fine, but Firefox users get a "No response from Stripe.js" error.

Comment: This is a nice start. I ran into some tricks with replacing 'live' since it is deprecated now, but this seems to be working for me. I used: `$('#gform_wrapper_1').on('click', '.gform_button', function() {` and replaced `_this.die('click')` (also deprecated) with `_this.off('click');`. Thanks.